# Please suggest the gallery plugin name with good animations effects and lookwise also good?

Tags: wordpress

I have used two three galley plugins but that was not with good animation and overylay effect.

So i want the free galley plugin which will includes showing images and videos categorywise and also having good animations effects and good to look. please suggest me two three such plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at StackOverflow rules as we are not supposed to answer questions based off of our personal opinions. Instead of doing that, and staying within the guidelines, here are plugins that Wordpress has on their website: [Wordpress Gallery Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/gallery/)